# Undefined variable: posts (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\QuickLMSzxc1\QuickLMSzxc1\resources\views\index.blade.php)

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

Here is my code:

**Show.blade.php**

[image]

**PostController.php**
[image]

**Index.blade.php**

[image]

**routes/web.php**

[image]

I get an **ERROR**:

[image]

Comment: Hello, Put your code in question don't upload an image

Comment: upload your code instead of images

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, i'm just rookie here. later i will upload my codes.

Answer (score 0):

You have to provide more details on route/web.php. Also, please upload your code instead of images. I would say you might missed something that's crucial.

Notice that when you access 127.0.0.1:8000, '/' part in your route/web.php would be triggered. You can find something like `Route::get('/', 'SomeController@index')` in route/web.php. Basically it means if '/' is accessed (normally homepage), Laravel would serve your browser index function from SomeController. Thus, simply change your route/web.php as following.

`Route::get('/', 'PostController@index');`

You may see your desired page with url 127.0.0.1:8000

See more at [Routing-Laravel](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/routing)

If this is not the case, please provide us with more information.

Answer (score 0):

if you are pertaining to the word **posts** it means you were not able to past it to your view

example code:

```
public function myMethod(){
//your $posts variable for querying
$posts = Post::all();

//you have missed the part of passing the variable posts to the view
//in this case, we are passing the posts variable to the "myview" view using the compact function
return view('myview, compact('posts') );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly check whether $posts variable is empty or not by using 
@if(!empty($posts))